# How to properly use populate in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to populate a reference field in NodeJS using mongoose for mongodb interaction.
I have the following code:

Housekeeping model

```
...
user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
    required: true
    ref: "User"
}
...
```

User model

```
...
userSchema.virtual("housekeepings", {
    ref: "Housekeeping",
    localField: "_id"
    foreignField: "user"
}
...
```

Housekeeping router

```
...
const housekeepings = await Housekeeping.find({day:day, house: house})
                                .populate("user")
                                .exec(function (err, housekeeping) {
                                    if(err) return
                                    console.log("Username is: " + housekeeping.user.name
                                    )
                                })
...
```

This code results in cannot read property "name" of undefined (I do have documents in the database that should be loaded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the problem was that I changed the field name in "housekeeping model" from "owner" to "user" without updating the database and POST method.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using [Model.find()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.find) so your `housekeeping` will be an array. That's why `housekeeping.user` is undefined. If you want to find one document then use [Model.findOne()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOne) instead. Also you don't need to use `.exec()` with `await`. Just:

```
const housekeepings = await Housekeeping.find({day:day, house: house}).populate("user");
console.log(housekeepings[0].user.name)
```

Or:

```
const housekeeping = await Housekeeping.findOne({day:day, house: house}).populate("user");
console.log(housekeeping.user.name)
```

Comment: Hello, I changed the code according to your suggestion but the user object remains "undefined" and I've verified that the user with the given _id exists.

Comment: Can you post the result of `console.log(housekeepings)`?

Comment: `code` [ { _id: 60f45a4f05df551822a33247,
    title: 'Kooken',
    day: 0,
    house: '60f455b1e0394e12a226045a',
    owner: 60f4142ff55f81251a7224ff,
    createdAt: 2021-07-18T16:43:59.684Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-07-18T16:43:59.684Z,
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 60f46c5d0052261ea689dfd6,
    title: 'Vaatwasser',
    day: 0,
    house: '60f455b1e0394e12a226045a',
    owner: 60f4142ff55f81251a7224ff,
    createdAt: 2021-07-18T18:01:01.258Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-07-18T18:01:01.258Z,
    __v: 0 } ]

Comment: There is no `user` field in these documents. Even if there is no foreign document, the populate field will be null. Maybe you are using wrong model or field name